# Load external images via proxy

Tags: plugins, images, proxy

regarding the GDPR I would like to load the images from external sources via a proxy. I mean, via my server. So, in the end there are no connections to external servers.

I haven't found a plugin yet... Have you guys and idea on how to do that?

Kind regards

Comment: which kind of images do you get from other servers ?

Comment: JPG and PNG images